# Where did the field uniforms come from that the SG teams wear?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, costume

Since the Stargate SG-1 field uniforms appear to look like military uniforms, yet in some cases looking just a bit more stylish, I was wondering if the uniforms were actual military issue (perhaps surplus), faithful replicas of actual military issue, modified military issue, or if they were designed and produced by the show's costume department, perhaps more "inspired by" than "copies of" true military counterparts.

The Atlantis uniforms are obviously costume department creations; I am only focusing on SG-1.

Comment: The uniforms appear to be not surplus, but US military issue that was given to studio for their use. "*Working with a staff of ten, McQuarrie sourced her clothes from Vancouver and also New York and Los Angeles. She worked closely with a U.S. Air Force representative in designing the garb of the SG-1 team. In fact, the group's fully-dressed field uniforms are authentic military issue."* - http://sutpmar.home.xs4all.nl/n_star-info1.html

Comment: Bits of the uniforms were sourced elsewhere; http://www.rdanderson.com/stargate/features/2004-04-costumes.htm

Comment: Don't you guys hate it when one of the gurus here pops a comment which could be an answer to the question which we could upvote? Right?

Comment: @AcePL I always figured they did that when/if they did not have official sources for their answer, but that does not track with the above comment. haha. Maybe it is out of humility...

Comment: I bet he had already repcap'd that day.  I haven't today, so I used that as the basis of my answer and expanded upon it.  if @Valorum wants, I'll remove his quoted comment from my answer.

Comment: @Jeff - If memory serves, I couldn't be bothered to answer at the time. It was trivially simple to find sources that directly addressed the question.

Answer (score 8):

Per Valorum, in the comments:

> The uniforms appear to be not surplus, but US military issue that was
>   given to studio for their use. *"Working with a staff of ten,
>   McQuarrie sourced her clothes from Vancouver and also New York and Los
>   Angeles. She worked closely with a U.S. Air Force representative in
>   designing the garb of the SG-1 team. In fact, the group's
>   fully-dressed field uniforms are authentic military issue."* -
>   [sutpmar.home.xs4all.nl/n_star-info1.html](https://sutpmar.home.xs4all.nl/n_star-info1.html)

For more information, there is a [Stargate costume resource](https://www.sg-operations.com/SG-Costume_Guides.htm) (fan-made) which has sought to identify each of the specific props used.  Obviously, there were some cutom-made bits (like the SG-unit patches) but there are fan-made versions of those available.

Most of the typical uniform pieces (boots, jackets, pants, vests, etc) are sourced from the same places the US military sources them, and are available for civilian purchase as well.

For instance, the [SG-3 and SG-5 Marine off-world uniform](https://www.sg-operations.com/CostumeGuides/SG-Team%20Marine%20Uniform.htm) consisted of:

- USMC "Hot" or "Temperate" boots OR Black Magnum "Response" (formerly known as "Trooper") OR Magnum "Stealth" boots.
- Woodland BDU trousers (they use ripstop brand) OR or MARPAT Woodland or Desert trousers
- OD Green BDU belt (or tan/brown/black appropriate to the uniform)
- Green, pocketless T-shirts
- Woodland BDU jacket OR Woodland M-65 Field Jacket
- OD LBV, Molle vest or suspender-type LBE; PS vest.
- ...

It goes on and on, even down to identifying the specific pistol holster and canteens.

The above list is straight from the link, which also provides picture references for each item and information on where you can source it yourself.

In short, not only was most of the SG-teams uniform strictly accurate to military issue, enterprising fans have located and identified pretty much all of it and you can buy it all yourself.

Comment: Great answer. Have an upvote.

Comment: He likes me!  Valorum likes me!  Where is my fainting couch?!

Comment: Careful now. Sarcasm gets you a downvote....